# PHP - sort arrays within assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

*I promise you I've had a look at the many existing SO Qs about PHP sorting, including [this mega one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)*

I've got a PHP associative array, with strings as keys.  Each value is an array of integers.  I want to sort each array of integers, in simple ascending numerical order.  I'm convinced this should be easy, and I've found enough examples that I think I should be doing the right thing, but it's not quite working, so there's a typo or I'm an idiot or something...

**PHP:**

```
//Each fruit corresponds to an array (series) of integers
$data = [
    'banana' => [
        1,3,2
    ],
    'orange' => [
        5,1,3
    ]
];

echo "Before sort:\n";
var_dump($data);

//For each fruit, I want to order the numbers
foreach ($data as $key => $series)
{
    //Sort array of integers
    sort($series);

    //NB I wasn't sure about value/reference details of foreach loops, so I also tried
    //retrieving a series into a variable, sorting, and then reassigning back to the same key
}

echo "\n\nAfter sort:\n";
var_dump($data);
```

**Output:**

```
Before sort:
array(2) {
  'banana' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(3)
    [2] =>
    int(2)
  }
  'orange' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(5)
    [1] =>
    int(1)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
  }
}


After sort:
array(2) {
  'banana' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(3)
    [2] =>
    int(2)
  }
  'orange' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    int(5)
    [1] =>
    int(1)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the output the inner arrays of integers have not been sorted.  What am I doing wrong?  (PHP 5.5.9, Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a reference `&`:

```
foreach ($data as $key => &$series)
{
    //Sort array of integers
    sort($series);
    // OR
    // sort($data[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that does work, fast work!  I didn't do that because I found at least one commenter recommending against it, in general, because things behaved "unexpectedly".  Can't find it now.

Comment: @frumious Hm, can't say I've ever heard of that... maybe in some cases.

Comment: I also tried $temp = $data[$key]; sort($temp); $date[$key] = $temp - would you have expected that to work?  It didn't seem to. EDIT Actually it is now, wonder what I was doing wrong...

Comment: @frumious `sort($data[$key]);`